# Configuring RESTAdapter to not set the .json extension for get / list requests

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I'm using a cross domain REST api.
I have defined my custom REST adapter to trigg my API.
Pb is to remove the ".json" automaticaly set by ember-model.

How to configure my adapter to avoid setting my "replace function" (**url=url.replace('.json', '');**)

```
App.Book.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create({
  ajaxSettings: function(url, method) {
    var authorization= "Basic " + btoa("login" + ":" + "pwd");
    url=url.replace('.json', '');
    return {
      url: url,
      type: method,
      dataType: "json",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": authorization
      },
    };
  }
});
App.Certificate.url='http://mysite/api/v1/books';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to configure my adapter to avoid setting my "replace function" (url=url.replace('.json', '');)

Since ember-model does not provide any configuration option to change this behaviour, IMHO, your solution by doing `url = url.replace('.json', '');` isn't that bad.

Another possible way I can think of could be to reopen the `RESTAdapter` and override the `buildURL` function to not include the `.json`.

```
Ember.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  buildURL: function(klass, id) {
    var urlRoot = Ember.get(klass, 'url');
    if (!urlRoot) { throw new Error('Ember.RESTAdapter requires a `url` property to be specified'); }

    if (!Ember.isEmpty(id)) {
      return urlRoot + "/" + id;
    } else {
      return urlRoot;
    }
  }
});
```

But this is not that future proof if the original code changes and you want to update the lib you had to change also your override.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tx, sounds good. But it returns an error (Uncaught ReferenceError: get is not defined) ..

Comment: @fvisticot, sorry, edited the answer, it should be `Ember.get`